# cordova android sqlite multple insert in "for" loop wont work

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

it's written in ***javaScript*** file where i get id form *html* page in table, i have been done this in longer way both insert and getting ids, and it works, where i wrote lines for every insert and the only difference is different id-s. i don't see why it won't work **shortened**? help
then **it wouldn't event triger "deviceReady"**
    `function unesi(tx){
    db = openDB();
    for(var i = 0; i <pname.length; i++){
    if(pname[i] == null){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO player (name) VALUES("'+pname[i]+'")', [],         insertSuccess, insertdFail);},transactionFail, transactionSuccess);}}}`

Comment: do you have any error in console ?

Comment: @Hassan ALi building app is on android device, on pc can't show cordova errors :P, on phone i work with *alert* so when device is ready it pops up which in this case wont

Comment: Why are you using a separate transaction for every insert?

Comment: @CL. there can be 2 names min, or 8 max for inserting.. every input has his own id, so i know how many players. those names are shown as names of a buttons which i plan delete onclick.. i dont know, have a better idea? :)